# The Maximum and Minimum are both wrong also Maxloc and Minloc Are both wrong the rest prints correctly just those two parts

Tags: pascal, freepascal

```
program Loans(Input,Output);
    uses crt;
Var
    i,m,l:Integer;
    Month:Integer;
    LoanID:String;
    QUARTERS:array[1..4] of Integer;
    max:integer;
    min:integer;
    maxloc:integer;
    minloc:integer;

begin
    clrscr;
    For i:=1 to 4 do
    QUARTERS[m]:=0;

    For l:=1 to 8 do
begin
    Writeln('Enter LoanID and Month');
    Readln(LoanID);
    Readln(Month);

    if Month <=3 then
    QUARTERS[1]:=QUARTERS[1]+1
    else if Month <=6 then QUARTERS[2]:=QUARTERS[2]+1
    else if Month <=9 then QUARTERS[3]:=QUARTERS[3]+1
    else QUARTERS[4]:=QUARTERS[4]+1
    end;

    max:= 0;
    min:= 999;
    for m:= 1 to 4 do
    begin
    if QUARTERS[m]>max then
    max:=QUARTERS[m];
    maxloc:=m;
    end;
    begin
    if QUARTERS[m]<min then
    min:=QUARTERS[m];
    minloc:=m;
    end;

    for m:=1 to 4 do
    Writeln('Quarter ',m,' has ',QUARTERS[m],' loans');

    Writeln('The maximum number of loans taken is ', max);
    Writeln('The maximum number of loans were taken in quarter ', maxloc);

    Writeln('The minimum number of loans taken is ', min);
    Writeln('The minimum number of loans were taken in quarter ', minloc);`enter code here`

end.
```

Comment: You should actually put some text, e.g. a question, in your question. Do not put the entire text in the caption. And try to format your code properly. That makes it easier to read not only for us, but for yourself too. Then you would have seen your mistake.

Comment: The title of the question is seldom a good place to describe it completely.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely must format the code properly - then you'll see your mistakes with `begin/end`

```
for m:= 1 to 4 do
begin
  if QUARTERS[m]>max then begin
    max:=QUARTERS[m];
    maxloc:=m; //update maxloc here!!!
  end; //if
  if QUARTERS[m]<min then
  begin
    min:=QUARTERS[m];
    minloc:=m;
  end;//if
end;//for m
```

and you can change all your quarters code

```
if Month <=3 then
  QUARTERS[1]:=QUARTERS[1]+1
else if Month <=6 then QUARTERS[2]:=QUARTERS[2]+1
else if Month <=9 then QUARTERS[3]:=QUARTERS[3]+1
else QUARTERS[4]:=QUARTERS[4]+1
end;
```

to single line:

```
Inc(QUARTERS[1 + (Month - 1) div 4]);
```